# How to set field seperator in Emacs csv-mode?

Tags: emacs, csv

Can I set the field seperator(s) for the current buffer in Emacs 23?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure -- although, by default, you can only do so globally. To do so, customize the variable `csv-separators` (`M-x customize-variable RET csv-separators RET`) and add the separator characters of your choice to the list. (See `C-h v csv-separators RET`/`M-x describe-variable RET csv-separators RET` for documentation on the variable, including some caveats worth knowing if you're going to change its value.)

If you really need to apply the change only to a given buffer, you can try making the variable buffer-local by means of `make-local-variable` (e.g. `M-: (make-local-variable 'csv-separators) RET`), then setting the value for the current buffer directly (e.g. `M-: (setq csv-separators (append '(":") csv-separators))`). Be warned, though: I haven't tried this, and don't know whether or not it will work.

Comment: The make-local-variable approach was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

This expands on the accepted answer. I would have commented there, but need >50 rep for that. I just found this and the `make-local-variable` approach did not work for me. I found the variable `csv-separator-chars` and its doc says

```
Set by customizing ‘csv-separators’ -- do not set directly!
```

So using `customize-variable` on `csv-separators` worked for me as this also set the `csv-separator-chars` which seems to be the one really used when aligning CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me either: although inspecting `csv-separators` shows that its value is local, it seems to have no effect.

But since [May 2022](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs/elpa.git;a=commit;h=6c0a3754c357fe0c77ecb2bf34305d84de1f3d32) (corresponding to csv-mode-1.20, I assume) there is a dedicated function:

```
Add CSV separator guessing functionality

Add two new commands: `csv-guess-set-separator' that automatically
guesses and sets the CSV separator of the current buffer, and
`csv-set-separator' for setting it manually.

`csv-guess-set-separator' can be useful to add to the mode hook to
have CSV mode guess and set the separator automatically when visiting
a buffer:

  (add-hook 'csv-mode-hook 'csv-guess-set-separator)
```